# CodeIgniter Validation rules are not working

Tags: codeigniter, validation, email

I'm including custom error messages for each input fields for each validation rules.
The rules are as follows.

```
 $config = array(
'firstname' => array(
    'trim' => array(
        'label' => 'First Name',
        'rule' => 'trim'
    ),
    'xss_clean' => array(
        'label' => 'First Name',
        'rule' => 'xss_clean'
    ),
    'required' => array(
        'label' => 'First Name',
        'rule' => 'required',
        'message' => 'This field is required.'
    )
),
'lastname' => array(
    'trim' => array(
        'label' => 'Last Name',
        'rule' => 'trim'
    ),
    'xss_clean' => array(
        'label' => 'Last Name',
        'rule' => 'xss_clean'
    ),
    'required' => array(
        'label' => 'Last Name',
        'rule' => 'required',
        'message' => 'This field is required.'
    )
),
'email' => array(
    'valid_email' => array(
        'label' => 'Email',
        'rule' => 'valid_email',
        'message' => 'This field should be email.'
    ),
    'required' => array(
        'label' => 'Email',
        'rule' => 'required',
        'message' => 'This field is required.'
    )
),
'password' => array(
    'match' => array(
        'label' => 'Confirm Password',
        'rule' => 'matches[confirm_password]',
        'message' => 'These passwords don\'t match. Try again?.'
    ),
    'length' => array(
        'label' => 'Password',
        'rule' => 'min_length[6]',
        'message' => 'This field should\'ve atleast 6 characters.'
    ),
    'required' => array(
        'label' => 'Password',
        'rule' => 'required',
        'message' => 'This field is required.'
    )
),
'confirm_password' => array(
    'required' => array(
        'label' => 'Confirm Password',
        'rule' => 'required',
        'message' => 'This field is required.'
    )
));
foreach($config as $key => $fields) {
foreach($fields as $rule => $field) {
    if(isset($field['message']) && !empty($field['message'])) {
        $field['rule'] = preg_replace('/\[.*\]/', '', $field['rule']);
        $this->form_validation->set_message($field['rule'], $field['message']);
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, $field['label'], $field['rule']);
}
```

}

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

But `valid_email`, 'min_length' and `matches` rules are not working. Please help me to find out the solution. Literally wasting time on that. The work would be more appriciable.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the `min_length` and `matches` you should remove or comment the line

`$field['rule'] = preg_replace('/\[.*\]/', '', $field['rule']);`

it remove the braces  `[]` with it's inner condition that's required for the role to run

regarding `valid_email` nothing wrong with it , may be you need to check the field name in the view/form .

or you could simply use the traditional method :

```
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]|matches[confirm_password]');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', 'required');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_message('required', ' %s Required');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_message('valid_email', 'Invalid %s');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_message('min_length', '%s should\'ve at least 6 characters.');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_message('matches', 'These passwords don\'t match. Try again?.');
    if ($this -> form_validation -> run()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```